# asp.net core 3.1 asp-page-handler two work one does not (on same page)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a dotnet 3.1 Razor page with three buttons with asp-page-handler parameters inside the same form. The first and last one work (i.e., they go to the webpage with a handler query parameter equal to the string in the asp-page-handler parameter). The third one does not get the handler query parameter added.

Here's a code snippet (cshtml page):

```
    @page
@model RMP.Pages.Client.SurveySetNameModel
@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "SurveySetName";
   Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="breadcrumb">
   <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="/Client/SurveyList/@Model.intUserId.ToString()">Surveys</a>
   <span class="breadcrumb-item" id="breadcrumbText">Create New Survey</span>
</div>

<h1>Name your survey</h1>
<p>The name is for your purposes only, it will not be visible to people taking the survey.</p>

<form method="post">
   <div>
      <input asp-for="sinSurveyName" requried="required" placeholder="Survey Name" class="form-control frmInpt" />
      <span asp-validation-for="sinSurveyName"></span>
   </div>
   <br />
   <h2>Select a Type</h2>
   <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Standard</h5>
            <p>
               Use our survey to find out some information.
            </p>
            <p>
               Cost: 1 Standard credit
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-footer text-center">
            @if (Model.dctTypeAvailability[1])
            {
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Standard" asp-page-handler="Stan" />
            }
            else
            {
               <p>
                  <b>Not enough credits for this survey. Contact your sales rep.</b>
               </p>
            }
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Standard + Custom</h5>
            <p>
               In addition to the standard do this
            </p>
            <p>Cost: 1 Standard credit and 1 Custom credit</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-footer text-center" ">
            @if (Model.dctTypeAvailability[3])
            {
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Standard + Custom" asp-page-handler="StanCust" />
            }
            else
            {
               <p>
                  <b>Not enough credits for this survey. Contact your sales rep.</b>
               </p>
            }
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Custom</h5>
            <p>
               Write up to 10 questions
            </p>
            <p>Cost: 1 custom credit</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-footer text-center" ">
            @if (Model.dctTypeAvailability[2])
            {
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Custom" asp-page-handler="Cust" />
            }
            else
            {
               <p>
                  <b>Not enough credits for this survey. Contact your sales rep.</b>
               </p>
            }
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
<div>@Model.strFeedBack</div>
```

and the cs file (the relevant parts):

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using RMP.Areas.Identity.Data;
using RMP.Classes;
using RMP.RMPModel;


namespace RMP.Pages.Client
{
   public class SurveySetNameModel : PageModel
   {
      [BindProperty]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Survey Name is required")]
      public string sinSurveyName { get; set; }

      public string sinSurveyName_validation { get; set; }

      public string strFeedBack { get; set; }

      public int intUserId { get; set; }
      public Dictionary<int, bool> dctTypeAvailability;

      UserManager<RMPUser> _userManager;
      SignInManager<RMPUser> _signInManager;

      dbRMPContext _dbContext;

      public SurveySetNameModel(dbRMPContext dbContext, UserManager<RMPUser> userManager, SignInManager<RMPUser> SignInManager)
      {
         _dbContext = dbContext;
         _userManager = userManager;
         _signInManager = SignInManager;
      }

      public void OnGet()
      {
         intUserId = 0;
         if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
         {
            string strUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            intUserId = Int32.Parse(strUserId);
         }

         dctTypeAvailability = setAvailability();
         //            strFeedBackTest = intUserId.ToString();
      }


      public IActionResult OnPost(String sinSurveyName)
      {

         String redirectUrl = "";
         if ((sinSurveyName == null) || (sinSurveyName.Trim() == ""))
         {
            sinSurveyName_validation = "You must fill out this field.";
         }
         else
         {
            int intCurrentUserId = 0;

            //                    string strUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            intCurrentUserId = Int32.Parse(_userManager.GetUserId(User));
            int intTicTocDefault = TicTocLibrary.getApplicationDefaultTicTocPoints(_dbContext);
            sinSurveyName_validation = sinSurveyName;

            //Surveys.createNewSurveySubtractCredits(_dbContext, sinSurveyName, intCurrentUserId, null, )

            TblSurveyInfo objSurveyInfo = new TblSurveyInfo();
            objSurveyInfo.SinSurveyName = sinSurveyName;
            objSurveyInfo.SinUpdatedByUserId = intCurrentUserId;
            objSurveyInfo.SinCreatedByUserId = intCurrentUserId;
            objSurveyInfo.SinSurveyTicTocPoints = intTicTocDefault;
            objSurveyInfo.SinOnMarket = false;
            objSurveyInfo.SinProductPrice = "";
            objSurveyInfo.SinProductDescription = "";
            objSurveyInfo.SinProductBrand = "";
            objSurveyInfo.SinProductValueProposition = "";
            objSurveyInfo.SinStatusId = 1;
            objSurveyInfo.SinSurveyTemplateId = 1;
            objSurveyInfo.SinCusId = Users.GetCustomerIdByUserId(_dbContext, intCurrentUserId);
            objSurveyInfo.SinUpdateDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            _dbContext.Add(objSurveyInfo);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            // subtract a credit from the user
            Credits.subtractCustomerCreditAll(_dbContext, intCurrentUserId, objSurveyInfo.SinId, objSurveyInfo.SinCusId, SurveyTypeUtils.getSurveyType(objSurveyInfo.SinStyId));

            redirectUrl = "/Client/ChooseAudience/" + objSurveyInfo.SinId;
            return Redirect(redirectUrl);
         }
         return null;

      }

      public IActionResult OnPostStan()
      {
         return GenericPost(SurveyTypeUtils.enmSurveyTypes.Standard);
      }

      public IActionResult OnPostStanCust()
      {
         return GenericPost(SurveyTypeUtils.enmSurveyTypes.StandardAndCustom);
      }

      public IActionResult OnPostCust()
      {
         return GenericPost(SurveyTypeUtils.enmSurveyTypes.Custom);
      }

      private IActionResult GenericPost(SurveyTypeUtils.enmSurveyTypes enmSurveyType)
      {
         String redirectUrl = "";
         if ((sinSurveyName == null) || (sinSurveyName.Trim() == ""))
         {
            sinSurveyName_validation = "You must fill out this field.";
            dctTypeAvailability = setAvailability();
         }
         else
         {
            int intCurrentUserId = 0;
            string strMessage = "";
            int intSurveyId = 0;

            //                    string strUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            intCurrentUserId = Int32.Parse(_userManager.GetUserId(User));
            int intTicTocDefault = TicTocLibrary.getApplicationDefaultTicTocPoints(_dbContext);
            sinSurveyName_validation = sinSurveyName;

            intSurveyId = Surveys.createNewSurveySubtractCredits(_dbContext, sinSurveyName, intCurrentUserId, enmSurveyType, out strMessage);

            redirectUrl = "/Client/ChooseAudience/" + intSurveyId;
            return Redirect(redirectUrl);
         }
         return null;
      }

      private int doSurveyCreation(string strName, SurveyTypeUtils.enmSurveyTypes enmSurveyType)
      {
         int intSurveyId = 0;
         int intCurrentUserId = Int32.Parse(_userManager.GetUserId(User));
         string strMessage = "";

         intSurveyId = Surveys.createNewSurveySubtractCredits(_dbContext, strName, intCurrentUserId, enmSurveyType, out strMessage);

         return intSurveyId;
      }

      private Dictionary<int, bool> setAvailability()
      {
         Dictionary<int, bool> dctAvail = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
         var typeVals = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SurveyTypeUtils.enmSurveyTypes));
         SurveyTypeUtils.ISurveyType objSurveyType;
         int intCustomerId = Users.GetCustomerIdByUserId(_dbContext, Int32.Parse(_userManager.GetUserId(User)));

         foreach (var enmType in typeVals)
         {
            objSurveyType = SurveyTypeUtils.getSurveyType((SurveyTypeUtils.enmSurveyTypes)enmType);
            dctAvail.Add((int)enmType, Credits.creditsAvailableForType(_dbContext, intCustomerId, objSurveyType));
         }

         return dctAvail;
      }
   }
}
```

So, when clicking on the button that says "Standard", I get a post to the page with ?handler="Stan" appended and when clicking on the button that says "Custom", I get a post to the page with ?handler-"Cust" appended. However, when I click on the button that says "Standard + Custom", i get a post to the page with no query parameter appended.

What gives?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Owen

Answer (score 0):

I hate it when this happens. Post question to Stack overflow and then find stupid type-o seconds after posting...

So the answer to the issue is: There's an extra double quote in the cshtml file in the div class around the offending button...